# FirebaseAnimatedList itemBuilder Error

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm currently going through the Flutter Firebase codelab [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#8).

I've followed all the steps, but I'm getting two errors when trying to use the `itemBuilder` of the `FirebaseAnimatedList` widget.

#### Error 1

Relates to `sort: (a, b) => b.key.compareTo(a.key)`:

> The function expression type '(dynamic, dynamic) → dynamic' isn't of type '(DataSnapshot, DataSnapshot) → int'. This means its parameter or return type does not match what is expected. Consider changing parameter type(s) or the returned type(s).

Do I need to cast the `(a,b)` to `DataSnapshot`?

#### Error 2

Relates to the `itemBuilder` of the `FirebaseAnimatedList`.

> The argument type '(BuildContext, DataSnapshot, Animation, int) → dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type '(BuildContext, DataSnapshot, Animation) → Widget'.

In this case, it seems that the index needs to be passed in, and also that the `ChatMessage` is returning the wrong type. I'm unsure how to fix these issues though.

Below is the code I have.

#### build function of the `ChatScreenState` class

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('friendlychat'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
                query: reference,
                sort: (a, b) => b.key.compareTo(a.key),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                reverse: true,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                    Animation<double> animation, int index) {
                  return ChatMessage(snapshot: snapshot, animation: animation);
                },
              ),
            ),
            Divider(height: 1.0),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).cardColor),
              child: _buildTextComposer(),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
```

#### `ChatMessage` class

```
class ChatMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  ChatMessage({this.snapshot, this.animation});
  final DataSnapshot snapshot;
  final Animation animation;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizeTransition(
        sizeFactor: CurvedAnimation(parent: animation, curve: Curves.easeOut),
        axisAlignment: 0.0,
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage:
                        NetworkImage(snapshot.value['senderPhotoUrl'])),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(snapshot.value['senderName'],
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                      child: Text(snapshot.value['text']),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

#### updated code for `FirebaseAnimatedList`:

```
FirebaseAnimatedList(
                query: reference,
                sort: (DataSnapshot a, DataSnapshot b) =>
                    b.key.compareTo(a.key),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                reverse: true,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                    Animation<double> animation) {
                  return ChatMessage(snapshot: snapshot, animation: animation);
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because flutter beta is using Dart-2 which by default ensures type safety max.

To resolve error 1:
Change

`(a, b) => b.key.compareTo(a.key)`

To

`(Datasnapshot a, Datasnapshot b) => b.key.compareTo(a.key)`

To resolve error 2:
Change

Remove the `int index` from the `itemBuilder` function

and also add `new` keyword after `return` in `itemBuilder` function.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! Error 1 is resolved. For error 2, I still get: `The function expression type '(BuildContext, DataSnapshot, Animation<double>) → dynamic' isn't of type '(BuildContext, DataSnapshot, Animation<double>) → Widget'. This means its parameter or return type does not match what is expected. Consider changing parameter type(s) or the returned type(s).` So, it seems that a `dynamic` is being returned from the `build()` instead of a `Widget`, is that correct?

Comment: Of course you are returning a widget. It's supposed to work. Code seems to be good. Can you also update the code of `FirebaseAnimatedList`

Comment: Hey dude, you just missed `new` keyword at the return statement of the `itemBuilder` function.

Comment: Updated my answer to include it too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166099/discussion-between-colin-ricardo-and-hemanth-raj).

Comment: @ColinRicardo any update on this? In Dart 2.0 I get an error when removing the `int` from the itemBuilder function. Also, still getting that 2nd error with or without `int` in the itemBuilder func.

Answer (score 0):

itemBuilder has an extra parameter called index.

typedef Widget FirebaseAnimatedListItemBuilder(
  BuildContext context,
  DataSnapshot snapshot,
  Animation animation,
  int index,
);

So just add ", _" after Animation, that would fix it.